# how do I view a 2d array as 1d rec array even the C-contiguous check failed?

Tags: python, numpy

I know I can create a rec array from buf=x `y = np.recarray((5,), dtype=[('a', 'u1'), ('b', 'u1'), ('c', 'u1')], buf=x)`  or view it as recarray, when the x is c-contiguous:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 255, (5, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
my_t = np.dtype([('a', np.uint8), ('b', np.uint8), ('c', np.uint8)])
y = x.view(dtype=my_t, type=np.recarray)
```

However when the array has strides like `(3, -1)` I cannot use it as buffer:

```
x1 = np.flip(x, 1)
y1 = x1.view(dtype=my_t, type=np.recarray)
```

above fails unless I copy the x1. But this is quite clumsy when x is very big, I want to avoid copy the data and still view it as recarray, any idea how to do this? Can we some how obtain the contiguous data view of the x1 then automatically reorder the my_t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same goes for viewing the 3 bytes of a row as 'S3':

```
In [9]: x.view('S3')
Out[9]: 
array([[b'\xca4\xc3'],
       [b'\x9d-\xc5'],
       [b'6\xa9,'],
       [b')I\xea'],
       [b'k\xdcT']], dtype='|S3')
In [10]: x1.view('S3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-10-f01e970923e3>", line 1, in <module>
    x1.view('S3')
ValueError: To change to a dtype of a different size, the array must be C-contiguous
```

The dtype is used to interpret a block of bytes,here 3.  It does not use `strides` to process each block.  Since `x1` is a view of `x`, the underlying memory buffer is the same.  The 3 byte dtype can't work with the buffer while still honoring the -1 stride.  So developers have chosen to throw the error rather than choose between conflicting requirements.

===

An array of floats would have the same problem with a `complex` dtype view.

```
In [19]: np.arange(6.0).reshape(3,2).view('complex')
Out[19]: 
array([[0.+1.j],
       [2.+3.j],
       [4.+5.j]])
In [20]: np.flip(np.arange(6.0).reshape(3,2),1).view('complex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-20-65e69d809ec2>", line 1, in <module>
    np.flip(np.arange(6.0).reshape(3,2),1).view('complex')
ValueError: To change to a dtype of a different size, the array must be C-contiguous
```

===

You can change the order of fields:

```
In [22]: x.view(my_t)
Out[22]: 
array([[(202,  52, 195)],
       [(157,  45, 197)],
       [( 54, 169,  44)],
       [( 41,  73, 234)],
       [(107, 220,  84)]], dtype=[('a', 'u1'), ('b', 'u1'), ('c', 'u1')])

In [24]: x.view(my_t)[['c','b','a']]
Out[24]: 
array([[(195,  52, 202)],
       [(197,  45, 157)],
       [( 44, 169,  54)],
       [(234,  73,  41)],
       [( 84, 220, 107)]],
      dtype={'names':['c','b','a'], 'formats':['u1','u1','u1'], 'offsets':[2,1,0], 'itemsize':3})
```

Note the new `offsets` key.  In recent numpy versions this sort of multifield indexing produces a view (earlier ones made a copy).  See the structured array docs. Compare that with the flip:

```
In [30]: x1
Out[30]: 
array([[195,  52, 202],
       [197,  45, 157],
       [ 44, 169,  54],
       [234,  73,  41],
       [ 84, 220, 107]], dtype=uint8)
```

It still doesn't allow us to use a view on `x1`.

Comment: I've figured out how to do it in pretty much the general case, though it a bit hacky now: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/20694. The PR is for string slicing, but clearly the method applies everywhere, as your first sentences indicate.